# Laravel apiResource route can't load instance

Tags: laravel, api

I developp an api with `laravel 10`, so I have `MarqueVehicule` model and I have this api route :

```
Route::apiResource('vehicule-marque', VehiculeMarqueController::class);
```

controller fucntion:

```
    public function show(VehiculeMarque $marque)
    {
        dd($marque);
        // but when I do  $m = VehiculeMarque::findOrFail($marque); it works 
        return new VehiculeMarqueResource($marque);
    }
```

In font-end I have this request : 
`axio.get('/api/vehicule-marque/${id}')`
the id is correct
but When I dd the instance I have null : 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it, the issue is that I initialise the variable in the function with a different name than the route :

route is  : `api/vehicule-marque/{vehicule-marque}` 
so the function does have `VehiculeMarque $vehiculeMarque` not `$marque`

Comment: "Implicit Route Model Binding"